# roaming detection in android

Tags: android

I'm trying  to detect when the roaming activation occurs. So far I've used the following piece of code, but because I haven't been able to test it I am unaware of it's correctness

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 

PhoneStateListener cellLocationListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
  if(telephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()
  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in roaming",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
 }
};

telephonyManager.listen(cellLocationListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION);
```

I've written this , thinking that in order for roaming to activate first the signal cell must change. Please let me know whether my deduction is correct or not, and if not how could I accomplish this.

Comment: You could test this very easily in the Emulator I think.
If you switch to the DDMS Debugging Perspective in Eclipse you can select your emulator and then select roaming in the emulator controls from the data chooser. 

This should trigger a change between roaming and not. The problem is that it may use a different way to go from state to state in the emulator then an actual device would go. 

Is it working in the emulator?

Comment: I'm working in other IDE than Eclipse, one that doesn't have this option

Comment: You can do the same thing via telnet on the emulator console. 
Look at http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#telephony You can use the gsm command to enable roaming.

Answer (score 16):

You can also test for `isNetworkRoaming()` in TelephonyManager if you want to know if there is Voice Roaming, even if the receiver is triggered by `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`.
I think this will also avoid the bug when the `getActiveNetworkInfo()` returns null.

```
public class RoamingListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony =
            (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (telephony.isNetworkRoaming())
            Toast.makeText(context, "Is on TelephonyM Roaming", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you suggest that your method is just for monitoring 'Voice Roaming'?  The docs for isNetworkRoaming() don't making any such distinction.

Comment: Thought of the same solution, I don't understand why they didn't just do this instead in that answer above.

Comment: IT IS NOT POSSIBLE to be in voice roaming but not be in data roaming. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783120/data-roaming-in-android

Comment: For SingleSIM, you are correct. But for Dual, this is wrong.

Answer (score 15):

I think you want to use isRoaming() in NetworkInfo class. But first you want to register a change broadcast listener:

```
<receiver android:name="YourListener">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

This gives you an action name: ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
//[edit: check for null]
if(ni != null) {
  //...Here check if this is connected and available...
  return ni.isRoaming();
}
```

[edit: known issue]
NOTE: There seems to be a **bug on certain versions**, where getActiveNetworkInfo() returns null if roaming. See here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11866

I hope this helps!

Emmanuel

Comment: ni returns null to me if I switch the emulator to roaming. Hrm... Be careful with NullPointerException there on the last line btw.

Comment: Good point. I'll correct this in the answer. Moreover, there seems to be a bug on some versions.

Answer (score 2):

Reliable way of getting event when Roaming state changes is

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
                super.onServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
                if (telephonyManager.isNetworkRoaming()) {
                    // In Roaming
                } else {
                    // Not in Roaming
                }
                // You can also check roaming state using this
                if (serviceState.getRoaming()) {
                    // In Roaming
                } else {
                    // Not in Roaming
                }
            }
        };
```

Whenever the Roaming state is detected , PhoneListener will be notified using serviceStateChanged method.

I confirmed this by looking at the AOSP source code.

CDMA

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/master/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/cdma/CdmaServiceStateTracker.java

CDMA LTE

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/master/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/cdma/CdmaLteServiceStateTracker.java

GSM

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/master/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GsmServiceStateTracker.java

Check the method
pollStateDone() , this is where the roaming state is set for the TelephonyManager

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm already listening for network state changes using the TelephonyManager and PhoneStateListener so, like the original questioner, I'm wondering whether roaming events can be detected there.

(This would be an alternative to using the ConnectivityManager/NetworkInfo solution in the accepted answer.)

To detect changes, the original question suggests listening for changes in cell location but I wonder if this wouldn't cause more events then necessary.

I would imagine that a change in the roaming state can only occur with a change in the network state.

```
protected PhoneStateListener psl = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state, int networkType) {
        if (TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED == state)
            isRoaming = teleman.isNetworkRoaming();
                // teleman is an instance of TelephonyManager
    }
}

public static final int pslEvents = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE;

TelephonyManager teleman = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
teleman.listen( psl, pslEvents );
```

There are two caveats to this method, but I think that the ConnectivityManager solution (in the accepted answer) has the same issues:

1. I'm listening for changes in DATA network state.  If user doesn't establish a data connection (e.g. they are just voice roaming) then it won't work, but I don't think this is a problem because most of us are looking to detect data roaming (e.g. so our apps don't use data when the user is roaming).
2. I'm not certain that there must be a change in data connection state when the user starts roaming - it is just my theory and I would be interested in hearing if anyone knows better.

Finally, let me add that it is possible that listening to PhoneStateListener::onServiceStateChanged() could be the best solution of all: simple and with the fewest unnecessary events (this should be triggered rarely) but I find the docs ambiguous and can't tell whether the PSL event gets triggered for a change in any of the ServiceState object's attributes (e.g. including roaming) or just for the ServiceState's service state attribute.

Comment: and where will u use this??? Inside the main Activity..but wat if my activity is in background since it doesnt includes manifest will it work?? I have a service running in background which again crashes in low memory by Processor..

Comment: If you want it to work even when your activity is not foreground then you should put it in your service, but even in your service, you are not guaranteed that it will keep running (as you note).  I guess you need to find an intent that you can list in your manifest, that gets fired when the roaming state changes - so my soln based on PSL is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

With Android 5.1 update, there is now a very easy roaming detection: just use the [SubscriptionManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html) and get a roaming info from [SubscriptionInfo getDataRoaming()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionInfo.html#getDataRoaming%28%29). If there are multiple SIMs, only the info from active one is returned, which is convenient.

Comment: SubscriptionInfo getDataRoaming() states whether the user has enabled data roaming or not in the settings, not if the device is currently actually roaming.

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly without any lisstener 
1 for roaming and 0 for nonroaming

```
try {
            int roaming=    Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DATA_ROAMING);
            Log.e("roaming","roaming"+roaming);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception","Exception"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
```