# Data roaming in android

Tags: android

Here's a question that comes from an unclear view of how things work : can a a phone be data roaming without being voice roaming ? If so how can a begin data roaming event can be detected ? This question came to me from the DDMS options , where one can have" data roaming " and  "home voice" .

Comment: Yes, the DDMS options are confusing. I tend to set them both to "roam" or "home" simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer: No!

It is not possible since the roaming services comes with the visited network asking home network if (1) there is a roaming agreement and (2) if the SIM-owner is allowed to roam. Thus voice roaming and data roaming is always done together.

Ref: [Roaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming#The_roaming_process)

Comment: Well there are Dual SIM devices,,,