# Unable to get data roaming status on Moto Devices Android?

Tags: android

I need to get access to the Data Roaming Status on Moto Device(5.0.1)

```
if (Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.DATA_ROAMING) == 1) {
    //Data Roaming Enabled      
    flag = true;
} else {
    // Data Roaming Disabled
    flag = false;
}
```

I found problem with this when using a Motorola device. Secure Settings in this device are found in `android.provider.MotorolaSettings.Secure` where as in other devices it's `android.provider.Settings.Secure`.

Is there a way to resolve this or any other way to get roaming status?

Comment: You could use reflection to test if the class exists : [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466568/check-if-class-exists-in-java-classpath-without-running-its-static-initializer)

Comment: How can i use it? Please help me on same...

Comment: I tried using this Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),"android.provider.MotorolaSettings.Secure.DATA_ROAMING") but nothing happens...

Comment: this could be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373779/roaming-detection-in-android

Answer (score 1):

One solution here, use reflection to check if Motorola classes are availables.
If they're not here, you need to use the default api, then call `getInt` on the available system.

Not able to test it on a Motorola device.

```
public static boolean isEnabled(Context context){

    Class<?> baseSettingsClass = null;

    // Retrieve the 'default' settings api
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
            baseSettingsClass = Class.forName( "android.provider.Settings$Global");
        }
        else{
            baseSettingsClass = Class.forName( "android.provider.Settings$Secure" );
        }
    }catch(Exception e){}

    Class<?> secureClass = null;


    // Try retrieve the motorola class
    try{
        secureClass = Class.forName("com.motorola.android.provider.MotorolaSettings$Secure" );
    }catch(Exception e){}


    // If it failed, use the 'default' api class
    if (secureClass == null){
        if (baseSettingsClass != null){
            secureClass = baseSettingsClass;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    try {
        // Retrieve the getInt method
        Method getIntMethod = secureClass.getDeclaredMethod("getInt", ContentResolver.class, String.class);

        // Execute getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DATA_ROAMING)
        int result = (Integer) (getIntMethod.invoke(null, context.getContentResolver(), (String)baseSettingsClass.getField("DATA_ROAMING").get(null)));

        return  result == 1;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: class not found : android.provider.MotorolaSettings$Secure and it returns false even when data roaming is enabled in settings

Comment: Class android.provider.Settings$Global has been found but always return false.

Comment: I don't know Motorola, I used the class you mentioned in your post.. Is your basic code working ?

Comment: Its working for other devices but for Moto Devices its not working. Checked in Moto G(gen 2) OS 5.0.2.

Comment: can you try with to replace motorola class with this class instead : `Class.forName("com.motorola.android.provider.MotorolaSettings");`

Comment: Using this class found, But java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException occurs at this line :  int result = (Integer) (getIntMethod.invoke(null,
     context.getContentResolver(),
     (String) dataroamingField.get(null)));

Comment: I found problem in logs : W/MotorolaSettings(28328): no such table to get this name = data_roaming

Comment: and what about this one `Class.forName("com.motorola.android.provider.MotorolaSettings$Secure");` ? (I can't find it on the web..)

Comment: Don't know may be motorola has added its api's over secure settings android, thats why it always return false

Comment: Is there any other way to get DataRoaming Status without using Secure settings?

Comment: I found some things, I edit my answer. (not able to test code for moto devices)

Comment: Where did you see that you could access `android.provider.MotorolaSettings.Secure` to retrieve this info ? I can't find a class with this name.

Comment: I found that in logcat, in most devices I get android.provider.Settings.Secure, where as in motorola device i get android.provider.MotorolaSettings.Secure

Comment: W/MotorolaSettings(786):no such table to get this name = vm_vvm_roaming_selection
W/System.err(786):java.lang.Exception
W/System.err(786):at com.motorola.android.provider.MotorolaSettings.getString(MotorolaSettings.java:290)
W/System.err(786):at com.motorola.android.provider.MotorolaSettings.getInt(MotorolaSettings.java:339)
W/System.err(786):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/MyTest(786):FailedToGetResult: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException